# Two startup objects rather than one

Tags: vb.net

I have created a console application using .NET.  Please see the screen shot below:

[image]
Why is there two entries for: "startup object".  SubMain is part of class c1 in the code.  I don't understand why there are two entries rather than one.

I have spent some time Googling this and I came accross a few similar questions on here, however I have not found an answer to my question.  The code is:

```
Class class1

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        MsgBox("Test")
    End Sub

End Class
```

"Test" is displayed to the screen regardless of which option I choose from the drop down list.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: how does your Solution Explorer looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting sub main will scan all modules for a `Public Sub Main`.  Selecting the class `c1` will limit the search for Sub Main to that class.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  +1.  It will also scan for Sub Main in classes as well (I believe) - I have just tested this.  Can you confirm?

Comment: I would suspect you are correct, however I am not in front of a machine with VS on it.  If you observe this behaviour then it's a good bet that its true.